# python styling ** question

Tags: python, coding-style, pylint

I'm working on my first project using Python 2.7. We're coming from a Java background and our first instinct was to write python code in a Java-esque way. But now we're trying to adapt as much as possible. So far we are using *pylint* to adapt our code.

Now I keep running into a situation with *pylint*. Every time I use something like `**data` to pass values to a method I'm getting a *pylint* warning about using `*` or `**`. Now my question is: Is using `**` a bad styling for writing python code? Is there some kind of standard replacement for using this ?

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: Could you paste some example of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`**` can introduce some more tricky bug because it will accept anything. Usually you want code that breaks when called wrong. Here is a example:

```
def dostuff(**kwargs):
 force = 3
 if kwargs.get('reallyhard', False):
     force += 5 
 # and so on

# Now you need luck to find this bug  ...
dostuff(fancy=True, funky=False, realyhard=True)
```

You shouldn't use `**` just because you are too lazy to type out the argument names. That is not always possible though, so there are legitimate uses too.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. It would be very hard to do what we need otherwise. For example we have a lauch method that recieves an adapter instance created dinamically by introspection each with a different interface. So the input data required differs from adapter to adapter.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost impossible to use static analysis to verify that the arguments generated by `**` are all valid, but if it is the only appropriate mechanism them by all means do use it.

Answer (score 2):

`**` excellent for what it is designed for: to forward arguments to other functions. You can definitely do bad things that will decrease the readability of your code with it, but it's not considered bad practice per se.